# No exact matches in call to initializer - Swift 2D array

Tags: swift

I was creating simple quiz app, when problem occurred.

I have an IBOutlet connection to UILabel:

`@IBOutlet weak var questionText: UILabel!`

And array with questions and correct answers:

```
let questions = [["1 + 1 = 2", true],
                     ["2 + 2 * 2 = 8", false],
                     ["It's third question", true]]
```

**"Cannot assign value of type 'Any' to type 'String'"** error here, when changing question:

```
func nextQuestion(num: Int){
        questionNum += 1
        questionText.text = questions[num][0] // <- error is here
    }
```

When I've tried force string, **"no exact matches in call to initializer"** appeared, even when I'm telling that this is a string and there is no reason to computing about it:
`questionText.text = String(questions[num][0])`

The only working code is:

`questionText.text = questions[num][0] as? String`

I bother why? I can't understand why **String()** is wrong and **as!** produces warning **"Treating a forced downcast to 'String' as optional will never produce 'nil'"**:

`questionText.text = questions[num][0] as! String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to suggestion about using struct, I've managed to create a new file in my project, where I defined question structure.

```
struct Question{
    let title: String
    let answer: Bool
    
    init(title: String, answer: Bool){
        self.title = title
        self.answer = answer
    }
}
```

Then I was able to create questions as above.

```
let questions = [
        Question(title: "1 + 1 = 2", answer: true),
        Question(title: "2 + 2 * 2 = 8", answer: false),
        Question(title: "It's third question", answer: true)
    ]
```

```
questions[questionNum].title
questions[questionNum].answer
```

Answer (score 1):

With your declaration, the type of `questions` is `[[Any]]`, which is causing the error you have described.

You should better do things in a type-safe way.

```
    let questions = [
        ("1 + 1 = 2", true),
        ("2 + 2 * 2 = 8", false),
        ("It's third question", true)
    ]

    func nextQuestion(num: Int){
        questionNum += 1
        questionText.text = questions[num].0
    }
```

Or defining a struct for the Element of `questions` would be more preferable way.